# How remove a header and footer with affecting the styling in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, templates

Im trying to remove the header and footer from a template page I wordpress via a custom php template, but want to keep the original styling of the theme.
I have successfully removed the footer, but am stuck on the header, everything I make an adjustment I loose the styling or I get a blank screen.

```html
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: No Header or Footer
 * This template will only display the content you entered in the page editor
 */
?>
<?php
get_header();
if (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
 ?>
    <div class="mainrows">
      <div class="large-12 columns">
   <div class="leftside fullwidth">
     <?php 
    if(of_get_option('headertype')!='header3'){ $goni = "0";} else { $goni = "0";}
   $bgattachment = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_az_header_bg', true);
   $bgtext = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'titleofimg', true);
   if(($bgattachment)&&(of_get_option('headertype')=='header3')){  $klaz = ";margin-top:-70px!important"; } else { $klaz = '';}
   if($bgattachment){
   echo '<div class="wpb_wrapper" style="margin-top:'.$goni.'px'.$klaz.'"><div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">';if($bgtext!=""){ echo '<div class="txtwr"><h1>'.$bgtext.'</h1>';} echo '<img src="'.$bgattachment.'" style="margin:0 auto!important;float:none;display:block;text-align:center;width:100%" class="phoneup" alt="" />';if($bgtext!=""){ echo '</div>';} echo '</div></div>';
   }
   echo '<div class="wrap1170 inwrap">';
if (getmb("hidetitle") != 'yes') {

$bgattachment = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_az_header_bg', true);
if(!$bgattachment){
?>
 <h1 style="margin-bottom:15px;margin-top:40px"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
 <?php
 } 
 
 } the_content();?>
  </div>
 
 
      </div>
    </div>
 <?php
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Make sure you keep `<?php wp_head(); ?>`  That's how styles are included

Comment: For what it's worth, I consider this question to have been closed for the wrong reason. Whether it's a good question, well researched or helpful for future users is up to debate but it is quite clear for anyone who knows WordPress at medium to advanced level. In order to consider it unclear one would have to be unfamiliar with the WP ecosystem and page lifecycle and, in my opinion, one should refrain from voting on closing the question under such circumstances. I'm therefore nominating the question for re-opening.

Answer (score 2):

`get_header()` does a lot more than simply adding the top part of your layout. So what you want to do in this template is set a variable to `true` and use it inside both `header.php` and `footer.php` (if you want footer and header to be independent, add two variables):

```
<?php
$hide_header = true;
get_header();
...
```

And inside `header.php`, you wrap the HTML tags you want not to display inside ifs:

```
if (!$hide_header) {
   // existing code outputting the top part of the layout
} else {
   // here you might put a simplified version of the top part
   // opening any tags that are closed later in the layout
   // also, make sure you call wp_head(). Your theme and plugins
   // depend on it to load .js and .css files
   wp_head();
}
```

You should also make sure you don't break the layout while doing this. Any tags opened in `header.php` must be closed in either main template or in `footer.php`.

In principle, you don't want to remove the calls to `get_header()` and `get_footer()`, as they are important steps in the lifecycle of a WordPress page and many plugins depend on actions called from those templates. You only want to prevent those templates to output some HTML markup.

---

**Note:** Depending on theme, disabling the top and bottom parts of your layout might prove difficult, especially if they have special positioning rules. Sometimes the simplest way to do it is by adding a class to `<body>` and simply use `display:none` on the elements you want hidden.

Also note most decent themes already provide an option for hiding the header and/or footer, inside the options page. Check if this doesn't already exist in your theme and all you have to do is (un)check a tick in theme options. Other themes provide the option not to display the header based on page-by-page setting, usually displayed in the page meta_boxes.

Answer (score 0):

All css and js are available in header.php

If you remove **get_header()**, header.php will not be loaded any more and no css, js will be loaded as well.

You can give the path of your css and js in your custom template you created above and then you can remove **get_header()**

It will work.